# On using logarithms to evaluate limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity, logarithms, exponential-function

The general method of using logs to evaluate limits is $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=e^{lim_{x\to a}\ln{f(x)}}$$
And this makes sense usually; I assume you can only use this method when you can see the limit will be positive, so that you can use logs.

However, it isn't always apparent if the limit will be zero. How can you then use this method? If it ends up being zero, the algebra you use to take the log inside the limit no longer works, because the logarithmic function isn't continuous at 0, and your calculations would be incorrect.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is positive, then $f(x)\to 0$ if and only if $\ln f(x)\to -\infty.$

Comment: Okay, so your calculations *wouldn't* go wrong unnoticed, but if whatever you do with the logs inside the limit yields $-\infty$, you know the limit was zero. Is that it?

Comment: So the rule of the log having to be continuous is only there so that we get an actual value in the subsequent calculations, is that so? Because even if $f(x)\to 0$ and we took the log inside and got $-\infty$, we would still sort of get the answer, because $e^{-\infty} \to 0=\lim_{x\to a}$. So for *this method*, you only need to know the limit is positive to apply logs. Have i got it right?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Forgot to ping you. There

Comment: You usually take log only if the original limit is in some exponential form: $f(x)^{g(x)}$. This is done so that the power comes down and you can manipulate this to apply L'Hopital. Any expression of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is strictly greater than $0$, so you safely take log. Do you have any examples of limit problem whose solution involves taking log (in order to simplify it) and is not in the form: $f(x)^{g(x)}$?

Comment: @Sid: no, but what if the limits of f and g tend to, say, -1 and 1/3 respectively?

Comment: then the limit is undefined i think, whenever there an exponential limit the base should be positive.

Comment: You should recall that exponential function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=a^x$ is defined for $a\gt 0$. Do you see what happens when $a$ is negative?

Comment: Yeah... Can't we treat f and g not as functions but just as expressions, then? They would still be defined if x doesn't have values that give imaginary roots.

Comment: @HarryHolmes: If $a$ is negative, $a^x$ will also have complex values for any non-integral values.

Comment: If limit of $f$ is -ve then there also exists a nbd (deleted) of $f$ where $f$ is negative and so you can't take its logarithm.

Comment: @Koro: Yes, so you do have to check whether it's negative, right?

Comment: @Koro: please respond.

Comment: If the function is negative in some nbd, then taking log is not possible in that nbd. But then that is not the only method to evaluate limits. You can use other methods which don't require taking log.